# Android-NDK's GGC/C++ appears to be erratic for std::string::find/std::getline(...)

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Appears that `std::string::find(char ch)` and `std::getline(stream, str, delim)` are erratic  for negative characters; on Android NDK R6B. Basically `std::string::find returns` `std::string::npos`, for say when character is `0xEB`.  Has any one observed any issue with them? They appear to work fine for MSVC.

Answer (score 1):

Characters are signed by default in MSVC, unsigned by default in GCC on NDK. To change that, add the following line to Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS) -fsigned-char
```

This might C break library functions that take a character argument, like `strchr`. The problem is that they take that character as an `int`, and the rules of expanding char to int vary with that compiler setting, if the char is negative/over 0x7F. With signed char setting, negative char values are extended with the 1 bit to negative integers, with unsigned chars they're extended with the 0 bit to positive integers below 256. The library expects the latter.

I ended up redefining `strchr` in my project like this:

```
// In the common header
extern char *strchr_sb(const char *s, int c);
#define strchr strchr_sb

// Elsewhere
#undef strchr
char *strchr_sb(const char *s, int c)
{
    return strchr(s, c & 0xff);
}
```

Comment: I wrote following: 'char ch=0xEB, std::string s; s.find(ch, 0)'.  Here it should not matter whether char is negative or what for C++. The interface for 'std::string::find(char ch, pos)' takes a character.

Comment: The way you wrote, the string `s` is empty. Why are you expecting to find the character there?

Comment: `s` was filled in with data, containing 0xEB. Did not put that code though.